# Parse issues when trying to use "Examples" section in Cucumber feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, gherkin

No luck in googling on this error message

features/manage_hand_evaluator.feature: Parse error at features/manage_hand_evaluator.feature:21. Found examples when expecting one of: comment, py_string, row, scenario, scenario_outline, step, tag. (Current state: step). (Gherkin::Parser::ParseError)

Here's the setup I have for Examples section (there are no other Scenarios at this time, just this one after the "Feature:" section)

...

```
Scenario: Evaluating for current straights
  Given I am a player with <hand>
  When the board is <board>
  Then the current possible straights should be <possibles>

  Examples:
    | board | hand |    possibles                  | 
    | A23   | 45   | A2345                         | 
    | 3456  | 23   | A2345,23456,34567,45678       | 
    | 789T  | A2   | 56789,6789T,789TJ,89TJQ       | 
    | 45678 | 23   | 23456,34567,45678,56789,6789T |
```

I also have step definitions set up already for those "Given, When, Then" lines (and tests passes fine when I replace , ,  with some text and comment out the "Examples" section). So it seems step definitions are set up properly, just that there is some kind of parsing issue with the contents I have in .feature file and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Relevant gems installed:
Gherkin (2.1.5) (tried 2.2.0 but it breaks with my version of Cucumber)
Cucumber (0.8.5)
Cucumber-Rails (0.3.2)
Rails (2.3.8)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Replace

```
Scenario:
```

with

```
Scenario Outline:
```

Comment: Voted this up now that I have sufficient privileges

Comment: This worked for me too however as a note to others the reason mine was failing was slightly different. Although I had "Scenario Outline:" there were two spaces rather than just one between 'Scenario' and 'Outline' which was causing the same parse error. Making it one space fixed it

Comment: In my case I had a space between Outline and the colon! Thanks to  your comment I spotted it; after some time.

Answer (score 3):

When you have tests that extends to having examples, you should always use `Scenario Outline`. `Scenario` is for those kind of tests with not more than one data to be inputted to test.